# Multiple date picker is not selecting multiple dates in one time

Tags: jquery

I have put multiple date picker on my site. It's picking multiple dates but not pick dates in one time. I mean after pick one date I have to do re-focus on input field than i can pick second date. This process I have do for pick each date.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="form-input"/>
```

**Js codes**:

```
$('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
```

Comment: `multiDatesPicker()` is not a standard jQuery function. By which library is this function provided? Is it this: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: I have used library http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js. Than I am facing this problem.